# access divs of same class name using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following html code-

```
<div class="search_results">...</div>
<div class="search_results">...</div>
<div class="search_results">...</div>
```

The divs are automatically generated by a javasciprt function. Is there a way to access only the first div/or a specific div of the same class name "search_results" with javascript?

Comment: Where you need to access a div? In javascript or maybe in a css? You can access it from javascript using a css-selector and JQuery or Prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use JQuery  `$(".search_results").first()`. Else you need to use `document.getElementsByClassName("search_results")[0];`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) which returns a NodeList (which is an array-like object). You can then access individual elements of that using normal array syntax. This example will return the first element:

```
var firstDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("search_results")[0];
```

Or, you could use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelector), which returns the first element found:

```
var firstDiv = document.querySelector(".search_results");
```

If you want to return all matched elements, you can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll), which returns a NodeList, like `getElementsByClassName`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getElementsByClassName` or `querySelector` (if available):

```
function findElementsByTagNameAndClassName(tag, class_name) {
  if(typeof document.querySelector !== 'undefined') {
     return document.querySelector(tag + ' .' + class_name);
  }

  var els = document.getElementsByClassName(class_name);
  var result = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < els.length; ++i) {
     if(els[i].nodeName === tag) {
        result.push(els[i]);
     }
  }
  return result;
}

var firstDiv = findElementsByTagNameAndClassName('div', 'search_results')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JQuery:

$("div.search_results").first() for later versions of JQuery and $("div.search_results")[0] for older ones.

No Jquery:
document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: The OP is asking for a pure JS solution. jQuery is not tagged.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a specific instance, you will want to add an id attribute to the elements, for example:

```
<div class="search_results" id="result_1">...</div>
<div class="search_results" id="result_2">...</div>
<div class="search_results" id="result_3">...</div>
```

If that's not an option, you can access the n'th item with the classname (starting from 0) using

```
var divN = document.getElementsByClassName("search_results")[n];
```